# RadCloudUpload size validation failed issue in c# telerik

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, telerik, cloud

I am new in RadCloudUpload in Telerik. I am working on Amazon s3 Bucket. When I am uploading small images (87.9 KB)(b.jpg) it is working fine with RadCloudUpload control but when I am trying to upload another image with size 4.15 MB (a.jpg) , the control is firing an error saying "Size validation failed". I am using the below mentioned code:

```
 <telerik:RadCloudUpload ID="RadCloudUpload1" runat="server" MaxFileSize="3145728" RenderMode="Lightweight" MultipleFileSelection="Automatic"  OnFileUploaded="RadCloudUpload1_FileUploaded" ProviderType="Amazon" >
        </telerik:RadCloudUpload>
```

I have tested the same from below link also (same issue exist) :

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/cloud-upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx?show-source=true

I am following -- https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/cloudupload/cloud-storage-providers/amazon-s3

​How to resolve the issue as I need to upload large size file(Images, PDF, Doc and etc) in Amazon S3 server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the instructions in this article https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/cloudupload/how-to/uploading-large-files by setting the maxRequestLength attribute in the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>

      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240000" executionTimeout="3600" />
      ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```